# Can the clang Static Analyzer be confused with return status conventions?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, llvm, clang, unzip

From: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/gles20/cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp

unzip.cpp and unzip.h look old and stable, yet I get the follow LLVM SA Logic Error:

```
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:1186:5: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:796:12: Calling 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:585:1: Entered call from 'unzOpen'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:687:13: Assuming 'central_pos' is not equal to 0
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:697:13: Calling 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:267:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:697:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:701:13: Calling 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:240:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:701:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:705:13: Calling 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:240:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:705:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:709:13: Calling 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:240:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is not equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:709:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:714:13: Calling 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:240:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:714:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:724:13: Calling 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:267:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:724:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:730:13: Calling 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:267:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:275:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:279:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:283:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:287:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:730:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getLong'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:735:13: Calling 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:240:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:248:11: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Calling 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:213:1: Entered call from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:217:9: Assuming 'err' is equal to 1
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:252:15: Returning from 'unz64local_getByte'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:735:13: Returning from 'unz64local_getShort'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:760:9: Calling 'unzGoToFirstFile'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:1179:1: Entered call from 'unzOpenInternal'
cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:1186:5: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's being confused by the struct assignment in unzOpenInternal just before the call. Not sure how much the subsequent cast to unzFile and cast back in another function are influencing it.

As the code seems correct you may want to file a bug report to the clang group and/or to Apple.

Comment: @"Analog File": Thx, I was thinking the same thing as far as filing a bug report; though I will give the question some time to "cook". :^)